# Mocking out the theme in styled components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

my tests are failing coz my styled components are using the theme passed down from styled-components `<ThemeProvider />`

but when I do this:

```
background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.backgroundColor};
```

it's ok

but when I do

```
background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.background.color};
```

it blows up saying it cannot `read color of undefined` and I'm confused why it allows one and not the other?

in the code itself it works fine but the tests are failing, how can I pass down the theme so the tests all pass again?

and why does it work for the first and not the second?

Comment: What tests are you using?  I believe JSX uses backgroundColor because .color is reserved for JS.

Comment: but `backgroundColor` is working. the tests are not even running coz it's coming through as undefined from styled components

Answer (score 1):

That's because the background is not defined in the theme object and you are getting an error that says `cannot read property color of undefined`. You can override/add some properties to the theme. You have to add background.color in the theme. See [styled-component theming](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#theming) for how to define some properties to the theme and use them.

This an example on styled-component documents:

```
// Define what props.theme will look like. this object can be imported as a global theme options.
const theme = {
  backgroundColor: "yellow", // -> `props.theme.backgroundColor
  // or
  background: { color: 'green' } // -> `props.theme.background.color
};  


// We are passing a default theme for Buttons that aren't wrapped in the ThemeProvider
Button.defaultProps = {
  theme: {
    backgroundColor: "red"
  }
}


// Define our button, but with the use of props.theme this time
const Button = styled.button`
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 0.25em 1em;
  border-radius: 3px;

  /* setting the background-color value from Theme options */
  background-color: ${props => props.theme.backgroundColor};
`;


render(
  <div>
    <Button> My background color would be 'Red' </Button>

    // Use <ThemeProvider /> to wrap your theme options to your components/elements.

    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Button> My background color would be 'Yellow' </Button>
    </ThemeProvider>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: which part shows how to add to the theme? this does work in the code, just causes the tests to fail

Comment: also I have defined them coz I'm importing my object into that file as the theme like: `import { theme } from '../../theme`

Comment: Check out the updated I added to my answer. Just define a `ThemeProvider` and pass a prop as `theme={theme}`.

Comment: Ive done this, the problem is for some reason it doesn't like deep object notation. so it allows `theme.backgroundColor` but then blows up with `theme.background.color`